# How to draw a Highcharts in opened modal window by using ui-bootstrap directive?

Tags: highcharts, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

My code is

```
  factory('modalWindowFactory', function ($modal) {

     var modalWindowController = _modalWindowController;

     return {
        show: function (title, name,data,confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {


        // Show window
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation : true,
            templateUrl: '/static/views/common/modal-view.html',
            controller: modalWindowController,
            size: 'lg',
            resolve: {
                title: function () {
                    return title;
                },
                name :function(){
                    return name;
                },
                data :function(){
                    return data;
                }
            }
        });
```

the modal controller is

```
   function _modalWindowController ($scope, $modalInstance, title,name,data){
    $scope.title = "";
    if (title) {
        $scope.title = title;
    }
    $scope.name = name;
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.chart = function(title,name,data){
        $('#detailChart').highcharts({
        ...
        })
    };
    //this line does not work!
    $($scope.chart($scope.title,$scope.name,$scope.data));

    $scope.confirm = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss();
    };
}
```

I bind a click function to open this modal,but when I click to open the modal window,there is only Text without any highcharts,my highchart code also worked alone,http://jsfiddle.net/3a33rqdv/

I don't know what to do now

---

I resolved it by using $ModalInstance.rendered.then,it's a promise type,thank you all

Answer (score 0):

take reference from following code and use same logic in your directive:

```
 $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
content: "<div id='container' style='min-width: 300px;display:none;
height: 200px; margin: 0'> <div id='Austin' style='width: 300px; height:
200px;'></div></div>",
 html: true
 })
.click(function() {
var chart_data = getChartData();
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart( chart_data );
$('#container').show();
});
```

[Here is my fiddle for refrence](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/d491945o/7/)